# how can I use "for loop" for evaluate char valuse to structured dataset

Tags: matlab

For vectors `a,b,c,d` and `e` as:

```
 a=[1 2]; 
 b=[3 4]; 
 c=[5 6]; 
 d=[7 8]; 
 e=[9 10];
```

I have a structure data as:

```
values.aa=a;
values.bb=b;
values.cc=c;
values.dd=d;
values.ee=e;
```

using for loop, how can I set predefined cells cahrs to vectors values as

```
a1=values.aa
b1=values.bb
...
```

?

Comment: But why do you want this? Seems a bit like an XY problem. What do you actually want?

Comment: What Bernhard said. The problem you describe can (only?) be solved using `eval`, which is considered *bad practice*. Please explain what is it that you're trying to do so we can give you some advice on better data structures.

Comment: That's why we use arrays.